# TypeScript: Cannot assign object to a new property of an object typed as a loose generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to figure out Typescript's generics, and I'm missing something very basic about them.

```
const testFunction = <T extends {[key: string]: any} = {[key: string]: any}>(target: T, source: T): T  => {

  (Object.keys(source) as Array<keyof T>).forEach(function (key) {
      if (!target[key]) {
        target[key] = {};
      }
  })

  return target;
};
```

– [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0BiBXMwoEtwwLwwB4AVGeADwTABMIYBvAbQGt4BPALhmgCdMwBzALqcAhmFYBfPPWZtOPPkNHiJAPgAUUEd37wonIgBouIFN2DwDASgMw8q+gChHd9QHkARgCt4GAHQsrBDqEKbm8FYwIrQAgtzcIqwEgSAAZjBEqlZ+qSDcAKIiwAAW6qloGNhgMOqBkXQudk2Y6eoAhFo6erKsgvWNTU2dulA9gtJ0EgDcA00SjRJWznbcembVw3oz00A)

Error:  `TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'.`

What's wrong with this function?

It seems to me target's type is defined in a way that should allow it to be modified with `any`thing. What am I missing?

Comment: What happens when I call `testFunction<{[key: string]: 1}>({a: 1}, {b: 1})` ?

Comment: `T extends {[k: string]: any}` just means that the `T` specified by the caller of the function will assign to `{[k: string]: any}`. It could be more specific like `{[k: string]: null}`, and you shouldn't be assigning a `{}` to something that expects a `null`. If you want `target` and `source` to be *exactly* `{[k: string]: any}` you should not be using generics. But of course the `any` "type" is intentionally unsafe, so that might not be what you want either. It's not clear what the point of this code actually is. Do you want this explanation written up, or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @jcalz `any` tells compiler that "nothing passed is safe", that's why compiler prevents any assignment? But then why replacing `any` with `object|string|number` doesn't help? I feel like it's a rabbit hole that's very poorly explained. I still try to wrap my head around this.

I can replace `any` with `object` and it will still prevent me from assigning an object there.

Comment: What I also don't get is why after removing `as Array<keyof T>` the `string` key becomes an issue, even if it's explicitly allowed by the generic definition.

And about what I try to achieve: I try to make a function that would deep merge two objects, but I cannot assign anything from one object to another because of these value/key errors that I fail to understand yet :/ .

Comment: `any` is like disabling type checking, since absolutely any other type is assignable to it *and* it is assignable to absolutely any other type (except maybe `never`); this latter part makes it unsafe.  It does not prevent assignment the way you're suggesting.  It's not `any` that prevents assignments; it's the *generic* `T extends ...` part.  If I say "I clean any car and return any car" then you shouldn't be surprised if I return someone else's car to you.  If I say "I clean car T which could be any car, and then return car T to you", you would be right to complain if I switched cars on you.

Comment: It seems you do not understand generics. Have a generic type `T extends U` means that `T` is *constrained* to `U`; it must be *assignable to* `U`, but you cannot assume that it *is exactly* `U`.  You're saying "for every `T` assignable to `U`, I will do something with `T`". By treating `T` as if it's exactly `U`, you will run into these problems, because certain things true of `U` are not generally true of every `T extends U`.

Comment: I'm happy to write up an answer explaining this, but I'm worried that you still haven't grasped the basic idea of generics and you'll be unsatisfied.

Comment: Yeah, when you write `Have a generic type T extends U means that T is constrained to U; it must be assignable to U, but you cannot assume that it is exactly U.`, my intuition tells me "wait! wouldn't `string: object` be assignable to `string: any` ? Why it doesn't let me do the assignment then?", it's like my mind fallbacks to the logic it's used to. It's the first time I'm dealing with generics, and try to understand them. I would be very happy to read an answer regardless, as I'm going to read up on theory of generics more, and will try to apply this knowledge do this answer.

Comment: `T` is chosen by the *caller* of the function, not by the *implementer*. You can constrain it but not choose it. Think of it as a type-level *input* to your function. As the implementer of the function it isn't really relevant that you found something assignable to the same constraint. If there's a function `addOne(x)` that adds `1` to its input and the implementer writes `return 3 + 1;` instead of `x + 1` because "`3` is also a number", it would be a problem, right?  It's an input, you must use it, not something else which could also have been an input. You're the implementer, not the caller.

Comment: Analogy to the `addOne` function is a brilliant way of putting it. Now I just need to figure out how to correctly approach implementation of generic if I intend to assign things. Because still, intuitively, if I restricted caller to `[key: string]: object`, one could assume that I should be able to add new properties to this object, whatever it is, just like JS allows it, but that's not the case here.